# Javascript bigInt's

Tags: javascript, numerical-analysis

I am just getting started on numerical analysis.

Let's say that i am performing some geometric operations in Javascript which require that i work with integers.

What is the biggest integer size i can work with?

I know JS can go to 32bit but with some libraries such as this: http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/ i can go up to 64bits.

I believe the logic here is to split the 64 into 2 pairs of 32bits.

Can the same logic be followed and enable one to perform computations on 256 bit number?
Does any library exist?

Comment: All numbers in Javascript are `float`. The concept of 32-bit and 64-bit numbers is meaningless in Javascript.

Comment: How many decimals points can i have in JS then?

Comment: @MikeW - You're sure they aren't floating points in a 52 bits [mantissa](http://kipirvine.com/asm/workbook/floating_tut.htm), and not of the type float which is something else.

Comment: As a sidenote, some browsers can go much higher, you can test it yourself -> http://jsfiddle.net/vnGt2/

Comment: @adaneo Type `float` means different things in different languages. Here, you're splitting hairs.

Comment: ok i still didn't get it. For 64bit i get a 52bit mantissa, no? If that is correct can i go higher than that using a library or something? Not native JS.

Comment: If native JS is an option, this could work: https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js
or an alternative that seems slightly more performant
https://github.com/indutny/bn.js

Otherwise you are rather limited to what browsers let you run any sort of native code at a lower level.